# Synology NAS: Trying to login after 2-factor authentication results in "wrong verification code. please try again"

Tags: authentication, nas, synology

I was not able to login to my Synology NAS (running on DSM 7) after I've enabled 2-factor authentication.

Searched a solution I ended up to this page:
https://kb.synology.com/en-uk/DSM/tutorial/How_to_reset_my_Synology_NAS#x_anchor_id9

But they suggest to backup the system and I was not able to backup as I couldn't access.
Well, probably I could mount the drive and backup from that but I wanted to find another solution.

Answer (score 11):

You need to have SSH enabled and your account need to be an administrator.

1. login trough SSH using your account
2. to add a password to the default admin account, issue this command:
   `sudo synouser --setpw admin 1`
3. your admin account should be disabled, so you need to enable it in order to access trough the web interface. To do so:
   `sudo synouser --modify admin admin 0 me@email.com`
4. now open the web interface and you will be able to login as `admin`, use password `1`.
5. open "control panel" > "users & groups"
6. select the user that cannot login anymore and click on Edit
7. disable 2-factor authentication

sign out and you will be able to login again.

Be sure to disable the 'admin' account again for security reasons.

Some useful info came from this document:
https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Firmware/DSM/All/enu/Synology_DiskStation_Administration_CLI_Guide.pdf

Comment: This got me back in when my 2-factor flaked out. Really appreciate it!

Comment: After replacing/upgrading my second out of 4 drives, I could no longer login with 2FA. Enabling the admin as mentioned above helped me get back into the webadmin.

Comment: After step 4, it requests me also 2FA for admin account, what to do now? This helped: https://diktiosolutions.eu/en/synology/synology-reset-two-factor-authentication/

Comment: omg thank you so much, you're a hero. So glad I still had SSH access

Answer (score 2):

Search in the settings for "NTP". You will then find a "Regional Options" Pane where you can set the NTP-Server. A simple synchronize now solved my problem.

Comment: Well I wasn’t able to login so no way to access settings.

Comment: solved the issue for me for "wrong verification code" in android DS File app

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to setup correctly your timezone.
For me the issue was that I live in switzerland, I had the timezone setup on the first gmt+1 I found. And I assume somehow at the daytime yearly switch, the 2FA wasnt calculated properly anymore.
I tried to sync the NTP  several time, and at the end I switched to the Paris time, which is the one applied in switzerland, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to login using E-Mail 2 Factor.
Check your auth app.
Reinstall you auth app.
Set your Timezone on NAS and Phone to your correct, e.g. Paris.

My las idea:
Login via SSH, Telnet excisting SMB connection, download all important files/send all important files to a cloud. Reset NAS manual.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a new way to break 2fa... have your drives completely full. Probably couldn't write a needed temporary file. Had to SSH to enable my admin acount, log in with that, then empty recycle bins. Then my 2fa started working again.

Answer (score -1):

If 2FA works well, then start to fail, you could login in SSH, then execute:

```
service ntp restart
```

In my case the service was stopped for unknown reason.